# Java - String NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, string, nullpointerexception

I'm making a mysql database connector with java to show all the data.
When I run the code, I get an NullPointerException in my `getData()` function.
here is my code.

```
public String[][] getData() {
String values[][];
try {
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM adresses");
    int i = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
    String id = rs.getString("id");

    String name = rs.getString("name");

    String adress = rs.getString("email_adress");

    String catagory = rs.getString("catarogy");

    values[i][0] = id;
    values[i][1] = name;
    values[i][2] = adress;
    values[i][3] = catagory;
    i++;
    }
    return values;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return values;
}
}
```

When the value of the String `values` is nothing I get The error. But if I give the String allready a value it says nothing .

```
public String[][] getData() {
String values[][] = {{"","","",""},
         {"","","",""},
         {"","","",""},};
try {
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM adresses");
    int i = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
    String id = rs.getString("id");

    String name = rs.getString("name");

    String adress = rs.getString("email_adress");

    String catagory = rs.getString("catarogy");

    values[i][0] = id;
    values[i][1] = name;
    values[i][2] = adress;
    values[i][3] = catagory;
    i++;
    }
    return values;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return values;
}
}
```

I want more data than that in my data String. how can I let it automatically do that??
Tnx.

PS.
The function is called in my class `FrameGUI` and has to change to `Object`

public class FrameGUI extends JFrame {

```
public JTable dataHolder;
Mysql mysql = new Mysql();

public String[] columnNames = {
    "ID", "Name", "Adress", "Catagory"
};

-> public Object[][] data = mysql.getData();

public FrameGUI() {
init();
mysql.getData();
}
```

}

Comment: Is this code compilable ? I doubt

Comment: Code you provided can't throw any exception simply because it will not compile. Can you post actual code you are using so we could take a look at real problem? Also including stacktrace of thrown exception would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize `String values[][]` so it is `null`. You either need to initialize it first or use a more appropriate datastructure like a `List`.

Comment: Local variables are not `null`s if they are not initialized. Only fields have default values.

Comment: The problem is still the same either way.

Comment: They have their default value and for references it is `null`.

Comment: Yes, solution would be initializing array with proper sizes, or even better using dynamic structure like List (as you mentioned). But claiming that `String values[][]` in this case will be null is wrong. It looks more like OP did `String values[][] = new String[size][];` (only one dimension is provided) and tried to use `values[i][0] = id;` where there is no inner array inside `values[i]` and in this case `values[i]` is null so `values[i][0]` could throw NPE.

Comment: It is visible in the code that `values` is not initialized. It means that `values` is `null`.

Comment: `values` is not field, but local variable, and local variables have no default values. If they will not be initialized compiler will not let you compile code which tries to use such uninitialized variable. That is it. To be able to throw NPE OP must had initialized it somehow. Otherwise his code wouldn't compile, which means OP wouldn't be able to run it, which means it wouldn't be able to throw anything.

Comment: The problem is still with `values`.

Comment: Agree, and your solution is correct. All I am saying is that your explanation of problem is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a class and use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (e.g. the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) instead.

e.g. if you want to call it `User` -

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //...
}
```

and a list

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

and then instantiate the `User` class for each row and add the new instance to the list -

```
User currUser = new User();
users.add(currUser);
//set values from result set
```

The list can grow automatically when needed and the code is much more readable than using the array.

Answer (score 0):

You get an index out of bounds in the first example because a String[][] (or String Matrix) gets initialized as a zero-length array.

In the second instance, you initialized the array to a size of 3x4 - that works so long as you only get 3 results back.

What you really need is a data structure with a dynamic size. Arrays aren't automatically sized dynamically. Try using a collection implementation like ArrayList or LinkedList or Vector.

Also, instead of saving your values to a String[], try creating a bean class that can hold your result. Create a new instance of it for each result that you get back instead of initializing a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't initialized your array, that is why you get `NPE`. Actually I suggest you to use `List` for your purposes:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getData() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM adresses");
        while(rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("id");

            String name = rs.getString("name");

            String adress = rs.getString("email_adress");

            String catagory = rs.getString("catarogy");
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(id);
            list.add(name);
            list.add(adress);
            list.add(catagory);
            values.add(list);
        }
        return values;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in you code is you are using arrays to save variable number of data. Arrays is fixed sized after they are created so you can't add (or remove) elements to them dynamically.

Instead of using arrays you should use an ArrayList object which have methods to add more elements. Also instead of creating a multidimensional array it looks like a better idea to create a class for the data you get from you database.

So lets first create a Address class:

```
public class Address {
    public String id, name, adress, catagory;

    public Address(String id, String name, String adress, String catagory) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.catagory = catagory;
    }
}
```

Now you can write you code as:

```
public List<Address> getData() {
    List<Address> values = new ArrayList<Address>();
    try {
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM adresses");
        int i = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("id");

            String name = rs.getString("name");

            String adress = rs.getString("email_adress");

            String catagory = rs.getString("catarogy");

            values.add(new Address(id, name, adress, catagory));
        }
        return values;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return values;
    }
}
```

The returned list will contain a list of Address objects which have the values from you database. Also, the size of the list is always the same as the content you put into it.